# Plotting Iteration in K-mean Clustering With MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, iteration, k-means

I have a problem with `kmean`. I would like to plot the value of the CostFunction ("`sum`" in the output shown below) vs. Iteration ("`iter`") obtained with the `kmean` algorithm. By altering the input options you can obtain this:

```
14 iterations, total sum of distances = 731.224


  iter   phase       num             sum

  1      1       604         847.577
  2      1        56         818.135
....
```

Using this data I want to draw something like [this](http://www.8pic.ir/images/97965487994257658420.jpg).

Comment: Please post what you're tried so far. SO users are not here for writing code for you but help you with what you've already implemented.

Comment: @AliTahoori Are you using the built-in matlab function kmeans? If so can you post usage?

Comment: yes i use built-in matlab function. only usage is really easy and fast..! why are you asking??

Comment: @AliTahoori so I don't have to guess where all the stuff you are showing came from... please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the iteration-by-iteration progress is apparently not being stored in some object which you can query you have to collect the info being displayed at the command line. One way to do this is as follows:

```
diary temp
% ....
% execute kmeans here, something like this:
% km = kmeans(H',nbin,'Display','iter');
% ....
diary off

% now extract the line by line result from the diary file called "temp"
fid=fopen('temp');
dat=textscan(fid,'%s');
fclose(fid);
delete temp

dat=dat{1};
i1=find(~cellfun('isempty',strfind(dat,'sum')));
ie=find(~cellfun('isempty',strfind(dat,'iterations')));
i1=i1(1)+1;
Nd=str2num(dat{ie(1)-1});
ie=Nd*4+i1-1;
dat=reshape(str2num(strvcat(dat{i1:ie})),4,Nd)';

iter = dat(:,1) % <-- iterations
sm = dat(:,4)   % <-- sum
```

There may be some way to streamline reading the `diary` file but this worked for me.

**Edit**

Before attempting to run a function it's always wise to look over the documentation:

```
doc kmeans
```

Comment: thanks for the code.but i cant understand that. i have to add this my code or not?? it seems not..! where is the input data? im so confused...

Comment: this is the error i recieve: "??? Undefined function or variable 'H'." after i defined it i recieve: "??? Undefined function or variable 'nbin'."   !

Comment: @AliTahoori Please see my changes. You should be able to use the code more or less as written. Just insert the lines you used to execute kmeans where indicated, and add the plotting function at the end of the script.

Comment: @AliTahoori By the way I don't recommend you use "sum" as the name of a variable as it conflicts with the name of the in-built function `sum`. I used variable name `sm` instead.

Comment: how can i increase iteration number??  (i think 'replicate' but im not sure)

Comment: i try this: '[idx,ctrs]=kmeans(cluster_data,3,'dist','city', 'display','iter','replicate',100,'maxiter',20);' but no change. i cant understand the different between 'replicate' and 'itermax'.

Comment: Please read the documentation for `kmeans` especially the part "kmeans can converge to a local optimum ..." . This means you want to repeat kmeans until you find the global mininmum. As the documentation explains, finding the global may involve a little luck!'

Comment: As for the options: itermax refers to the number of iterations during one kmeans execution. replicate refers to the number of times you are repeating kmeans, starting at (presumably) different starting points each time, to check that you have an absolute minimum. In the end just pick the result from the various replicates that returned the lowest sum error.

Comment: i try this format: '[idx,ctrs]=kmeans(cluster_data,3,'dist','city', 'display','iter','replicate',100,'maxiter',20);' but no change in iteration...

Comment: If you are not seeing a change then most likely its converged (you reached a minimum)

Comment: no, i think there is a problem here...because when i use less than 6 there is no change iteration. if i use 'maxiter' more than 6 there is no change too.are u sure the syntax of kmean (i mean with 'maxiter') is correct?

Comment: Please post as a separate question since I cannot tell what is wrong from the information you are providing....

Answer (score 0):

If `iter` and `sum` are stored as variables, you may simply call

```
plot( iter , sum , 'r' , 'LineWidth' , 1.5 )
```

or, simplier

```
plot(sum)
```

**EDIT**

I am not familiar with the function, but for saving as workspace variables I would do as follows:

```
[IDX,C,sumd,D] = kmeans(X,k)
```

and then just stay with what I mentioned above.

Comment: unfortunately there is no such this variable in workspace... i just use the default function im MATLAB. kmean algorithm. [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/k-means-clustering.html)

Comment: @AliTahoori : I edited my answer, check if it fits your need.

Comment: so how about 'iter' in this "plot( iter , sum , 'r' , 'LineWidth' , 1.5 )" ?  we can generate 'sum' by getting 'sumd' from kmeans function how about 'iter'???